# A maximal subgroup of a $p$-group contains all commutators and $p$-th powers of elements

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a p-group and $M\subseteq G$ be a maximal subgroup. Show that $M$ contains all commutators and $p$-th powers of elements of $G$.

**My attempt**

The commutators are elements of the form $[x, y] = x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$, for $x, y\in G$. So we essentially need to prove that the commutator subgroup $G' = [G, G]$ and the set $\{x^p: x\in G\}$ are both contained in $M$.

I think the fact that $M$ is normal and is of index $p$ might be useful. From this we can also deduce that $G/M$ is a cyclic group of order $p$.

But I can't really see how to draw the connections between these observations and the desired result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing that $M$ is normal and $G/M$ is cyclic of index $p$ is sufficient.

If $x$, $y\in G$, then since $G/M$ is Abelian, then $(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})M
=(xM)(yM)(x^{-1}M)(y^{-1}M)=M$ in $G/M$, that is, $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in M$.

If $x\in G$, then since $G/M$ has order $p$, then $x^pM=(xM)^p=M$
in $G/M$, that is $x^p\in M$.

Comment: Wow, these arguments are neat! Thanks a lot, Lord Shark the Unknown!